# Does an updated APK need to be verified on v1, v2, and v3 scheme?

Tags: android, apk-signing

Before re-uploading my updated APK to Google Play, I've used apksigner to confirm that its signature will be verified successfully on all versions of the Android platform that it supports. I got this result:

```
Verifies

Verified using v1 scheme (JAR signing): true

Verified using v2 scheme (APK Signature Scheme v2): false

Verified using v3 scheme (APK Signature Scheme v3): false
```

Do *all three* schemes need to be `true`? If so, what do I need to do on the command line to make the v2 scheme and v3 scheme `true` as well?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should sign it with command

```
  apksigner sign --ks keystore.jks |
  --key key.pk8 --cert cert.x509.pem
  [signer_options] app-name.apk
```

And **signer_options** inludes:
--v2-signing-enabled=true
--v3-signing-enabled=true

Detail is in [document](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/apksigner)